# What gaming resources for ubuntu(or gnu/linux in general) are there?

Tags: games

what websites(databases,news sites etc) are available ? what repos are there ?

include one resource per answer with a short description on the resource .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should probably start here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Games

Also, does anyone need another game besides [Minecraft](http://www.minecraft.net/)?

Gotta add one more. Everything from [Three Rings](http://www.threerings.net/) works great on Linux using the Sun JVM. Spiral Knights is getting some good press right now.

Comment: +1 I was going to mention a specific page, but it's mentioned on the one you cited.

Answer (score 5):

the one i officialy recommend is playdeb at http://www.playdeb.net/welcome/

You can install the deb repository by:

1. Add to your repositories (Go to your update manager and click on the Settings button)
   `deb http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu lucid-getdeb games`
2. Add the secure key for it
   `wget -q -O- http://archive.getdeb.net/getdeb-archive.key | sudo apt-key add -`
3. Update your repositories.

Now you can install any of the games that playdeb has to offer at http://www.playdeb.net/

The list has grown from around 20 games to more than 100 official games for ubuntu, ranging from RPG, Strategy, Logic, mmorpg, etc..

Another very good one is http://www.happypenguin.org/ which is a news site for linux games. Very old and very good.

Lastly the https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Games from Ubuntu has several list of sites that are very good also.

Answer (score 3):

For 14 days from now (2011-04-12), you can buy Linux-compatible games from the Humble Frozenbyte Bundle for the price that you set yourself:

http://www.humblebundle.com/

They've released similar bundles in the past and will most likely continue to do so in the future.

Other venues to look for games include Linux Game Publishing (commercial):

http://www.linuxgamepublishing.com/

Playdeb.net (free):

http://www.playdeb.net/

and Lutris (emulated):

http://lutris.net/

Answer (score 2):

There's another nice list of gmaing sites: http://www.penguspy.com/linux-gaming-resources/

Answer (score 2):

You can find a lot of game debs at http://www.dotdeb.com that are not available anywhere else.

Answer (score 2):

Some of them you will find it [**here**](http://www.ubuntubuzz.com/2011/07/best-website-to-download-ubuntu-game.html). at least 10 website that provide free ubuntu game for download including http://www.playdeb.net/ which has been write above. you can also play console game such PS 1/2/3 and Nintendo DS in ubuntu dude :)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at http://linuxgamingnews.org/

Apart from the site itself pay particular attention to the links on the left side "GNU/LINUX GAMING SITES" and "BUY GNU/LINUX GAMES !"